# Cannot convert 'wchar_t *' to 'char *'

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe

При компиляции кода:

```
float x,y,n,k; 

char* Str;

Str = Edit1->Text.c_str();

sscanf (Str, "%f %f %f ", &k, &n, &x);

y = k*sqrt(fabs(x))+x*n;

Edit1->Text = FloatToStrF (y, ffFixed, 6, 3);
```

на строке `Str = Edit1->Text.c_str();` возникает ошибка:

> [bcc32 Error] Unit3.cpp(22): E2034 Cannot convert 'wchar_t *' to 'char *'

Скриншот:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не вся программа. и тут не найти ошибку нам

Comment: Ждет строку `char*`, а ему подсовывают широкую строку `wchar_t*`. Где именно и что именно и как именно объявлено - смотрите сами...

Comment: @Harry собственно это вся программа.

Comment: @Harry скорее всего в третьей строке с кодом. Т.к. элемент GUI возвращает UnicodeString.

Comment: @Олександр Митровка  Используйте более вежливый компилятор, который не ругается!

Comment: @alexolut Охотно поверю :) Собственно, я код не смотрел, просто прокомментировал ошибку, чтоб было понятнее, и не более того.

Comment: @alexoult именно на 3 строку и выдает ошибку.

Comment: Код бессмыслен уже по своей задумке. `c_str()` возвращает указатель на константную строку. Возникает закономерный вопрос: а почему сообщение от компилятора говорит о `wchar_t *`, а не о `const wchar_t *`? Может автор что-то выдумывает?

Comment: @AnT возможно потому что [не всё так гладко](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__c_str.html) в мире Embarcadero.

Comment: @AnT вот скрин [сcылка](http://rgho.st/8CzZDfX5d)

Comment: Безобразие. Безобразие.

Comment: @AnT c_str() возвращает указатель на `CharT`, а уж что такое `CharT` - зависит от специализации.

Comment: @andy.37: Я веду речь в первую очередь об отсутствии `const`. Стандартный `c_str()` (в `basic_string`) возвращает указатель именно на `const CharT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, что `Edit1->Text` имеет тип `std::wstring` (или что-то производное от этого, например `CString`) и c_str() соответственно, возвращает `const wchar_t*`. Правильно будет написать (22-я строка)

```
const wchar_t* Str = Edit1->Text.c_str()
```

Comment: Что-то производное, это [UnicodeString](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString.html).

Comment: @alexolut не зная, что такое `Edit1` об этом можно только гадать. Это может быть `MyOwnVeryAttractiveWideString`)

Comment: Вы наверное никогда не работали в C++ Builder, если так думаете. В принципе, я Вам даже завидую.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам и правда надо `wchar_t*` конвертировать в `char*` то у вас два варианта, простой и сложный.

Простой

```
char buff[256]; // допустимой длинны
          // Строка в edit не должна быть больше чем 255
wsprintfA(buff,"%ls",Edit1->Text.c_str());
```

Более сложный WideCharToMultiByte  примеры [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839080/widechartomultibyte-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80/) указываете кодировку, готовите переменные и конвертируете.

Конвертация нужна если вы используете функции для `char*` (sscanf), это принципиально два разных типа данных. unicode может содержать много разных символов из нескольких алфавитов, которых в таблице ASCII может не оказаться, сегодня стараються уйти от ASCII к Unicode или utf-8 что бы не иметь проблем с кодировкой. Что бы не конвертировать - можно поискать аналогичные функции для `wchar_t*` (по идее аналог должен быть sscanfW но не уверен что он есть).