# WideCharToMultiByte конвертирует строку, но добавляет мусор

Tags: c++

Не понимаю, каким образом в строку с результатом попадет мусор, и откуда.

```
template <class T>
T* malloc(size_t size)
{
    return static_cast<T*>(malloc(size));
}

void utf8_encode(const wchar_t* input, char** output)
{
    int str_len = wcslen(input);
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, str_len, nullptr, 0, 0, 0);

    *output = malloc<char>(size_needed);
    memset(*output, 0 , size_needed);

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, str_len, *output, size_needed, 0, 0);
}


int main()
{
    const wchar_t buffer[] = L"Ｓｔｒｉｎｇ　ｃｏｎｔａｉｎ　ａｎｙ　ｗｉｄｅ　ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ　こんにちは";

    char* result = nullptr;

    utf8_encode(buffer, &result);

    printf("%s", result);
    free(result);
}
```

Comment: Функция WideCharToMultiByte не делает ASCII-Z, поэтому если после её работы вы хотите получить  ASCII-Z (которое ожидает printf) то добавьте ноль в конце строки

Comment: Опа, но почему если я делю его сам, получаю рантайм повреждение кучи?

Comment: Резервировать надо место под ASCII-z, т.е. size_needed + 1 (для нуля в char) или +2 (для wchar_t) , вместо size_needed

Comment: Добавьте ответом о `WideCharToMultiByte` на ＭＳＤＮ не видел онформации об этом.

Comment: Возможно ещё такое решение, если 0 в конце строки не требуется для дальнейших операций кроме printf: `printf("%.*ls",size_needed,output);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WideCharToMultiByte` конвертирует не ASCII-z строки, а массив. На выходе функции - идет char (байт). это означает что если вы конвертируете строку длинной size_needed  - то она сконвертируется, но вам нужен +1 символ, если стока должна быть не "массивом", а ASCII-z, т.к. большинство функций работает именно с ASCII-z. В данном случае я бы сделал так

```
*output = malloc<char>(size_needed + 1); /*Добавить 1*/
//memset(*output, 0 , size_needed); это лишнее
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, str_len, *output, size_needed, 0, 0);
(*output)[size_needed] = 0; /*Добавляем ноль*/
```

Если вам строка 2 - нравится, то строку 4 можно не писать.

Для `MultiByteToWideChar` длинна символа будет 2, поэтому будет `malloc<wchar_t>(size_needed + 2)`  (если size_needed-правильный размер).

P.S. Вижу преобразование кодировок, от себя добавлю. Если нужна конвертация с юникода в ANSI/OEM  есть интересный короткий вариант `wsprintfA(*output,"%ls",input)` и назад `wsprintfW(*output,L"%hs",input)`

Comment: На MSDN бы такое описание =)

Comment: В Remarks есть https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx но долго читать нужно. Правда не написано что делать если надо ASCII-z.

Answer (score 1):

`WideCharToMultiByte` имеет два режима работы: с массивом указанной длины и с оканчивающейся нулем строкой. Явно указывая длину входного массива `str_len` активируется первый режим, а для активации второго вместо длины следует передать `-1`, тогда функция вернет требуемый размер буфера включая ноль на конце и корректно его поставит во время конвертации. Соответственно считать длину строки самостоятельно не нужно, однако следует проверять возвращаемые значения перед использованием:

```
char * p_output{};
int const buffer_capacity{::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, -1, nullptr, 0, 0, 0)};
if(0 < buffer_capacity)
{
    p_output = malloc<char>(buffer_capacity);
    if(p_output)
    {
        [[maybe_unused]] int const bytes_written{::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, -1, p_output, buffer_capacity, 0, 0)};
        assert(bytes_written == buffer_capacity);
        assert('\0' == p_output[buffer_capacity - 1]);
    }
}
*output = p_output;
```