# Как сделать сравнение юникод строки из файла и const wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

Я перехватываю перемещение файла, в файле permission.txt через \n записаны пути до файлов, которые перемещать нельзя
Сейчас сильно остановился на больной для меня теме - кодировки. Не могу понять как взять строку из файла и сравнить ее с LPCWSTR:

```
    BOOL WINAPI MyMoveFileExW(LPCWSTR lpExistingFileName, LPCWSTR lpNewFileName, DWORD dwFlags)
    {
        std::wstring lpEx(lpExistingFileName);
        std::wifstream wif("C:\\cpp\\permission.txt", std::ios::binary);
        if (wif.is_open())
        {
            wif.imbue(std::locale(wif.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));

            std::wstring wline;
            while (std::getline(wif, wline))
            {
                if(wline == lpEx){
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
            wif.close();
        }
      BOOL retValue;
      VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress_2, SIZE, myProtect_2, NULL);     // assign read write protection
      memcpy((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress_2, oldBytes_2, SIZE);                            // restore backup
      retValue = pOrigMBAddress_2(lpExistingFileName, lpNewFileName, dwFlags);
      memcpy((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress_2, JMP_2, SIZE);                                 // set the jump instruction again
      VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress_2, SIZE, oldProtect_2, NULL);    // reset protection

      return TRUE;
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь вариант

Comment: Не сильно понятно где проблема, и есть ли она, посмотрите вайд функции [преобразования и сравнения](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/) если речь про это.. А по теории, юникод переведите в wchar_t и сравнивайте.

Comment: Если строка ANSI т.е. char* то её можно переконфертировать в wchar_t*

Comment: Может вам нужно это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839080/widechartomultibyte-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80/839095#839095 перекодирование

Comment: Сравнить две строки имеет смысл только если обе в одинаковых кодировках. Перевели - сравнили.