# Нужен пример использования g_convert()

Tags: c, utf-8, gtk+

У меня имеется следующая проблема: я разрабатывают интерфейс на **GTK+** в **Windows 10**.

Мне необходимо получить из диалога выбора файла имя выбранного файла. Функция **gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()** возвращает имя в формате **UTF-8**, а **fopen()** в **Windows** требует строку однобайтовых символов в системной кодировке, поэтому прямая передача строки в **fopen()** работает только в том случае, если в имени файла нет несовместимых с **ASCII** символов.

Для конвертации строки я пытаюсь использовать функцию **g_convert()**, но она возвращает **NULL**. Я не могу найти нормальную документацию и примеры, только общее непонятное описание.

Как сделать следующее?:

```
gchar *utf_8_s = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));

gchar *ascii_s = g_convert(???);

FILE *f = fopen(ascii_s, "wb");
```

Comment: Если конкретно винда интерисует, то для UTF-8 я вам рекомендую WideCharToMultiBуte и MultiButeToWideChar. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839080/widechartomultibyte-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80/839095

Comment: wide char != utf-8 char

Comment: Я знаю. В UTF-8 конвертирует `WideCharToMultiBуte`, но если у вас не WideChar то прийдётся сначало `MultiBуteToWideChar` а потом `WideCharToMultiBуte(UTF-8 грубо)`. Предложил "как быстрое решение". Возможно если долго не будет ответа - пригодится.

Comment: Это не подходит, нужен пример использования g_convert(), ведь эта функция предназначена как раз для конвертации *из чего хочешь в что хочешь*.

Comment: @Максим Что за странную метку вы изобрели `cc++`?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я разобрался.

```
char *ascii_s = g_convert(utf_8_s,// Указатель на строку в формате utf-8

                         -1,// Размер utf_8_s определяется по нультерминатору.

                         "CP1251",// Во что конвертировать.

                         "UTF-8",// Из чего конвертировать.

                         NULL,// Конвертировать все символы utf_8_s.

                         NULL,// Не вести учет количества успешно конвертированных символов.

                         NULL);// Не сохранять информацию об ошибке, если она возникнет.
```