# C++ curl получить utf-8 в кирилице

Tags: c++, curl

Есть документ в интернете в UTF-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь получить его в UTF-8 с помощю curl

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
  ((std::wstring*)userp)->append((wchar_t*)contents, size * nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;
}

...

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::wstring readBuffer;

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

int pos = readBuffer.find_first_of(L"World");
```

breakpoint на readBuffer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и pos

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему я не получаю в UTF-8 то что нужно?

Comment: Это и так кириллица в нормальной кодировке... Другой вопрос, что визуализатор текста в студии не позволяет выбрать кодировку отображаемого текста.

Comment: Вопрос должен звучать так - как заставить студию угадать кодировку и наконец научится отображать utf-8

Comment: Перекодируйте в `wchar_t*` и будет счатье. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839080/widechartomultibyte-конвертирует-строку-но-добавляет-мусор/839095

Comment: @VTT, а, понял, не знал

Comment: @nick_n_a, а в чем разница между char и wchar_t? std::string и std::wstring?)

Comment: Разница в том, что для с++ сред, консолей, АПИ "родной" формат (тот в котором вас программа поймёт) `wchar_t*` и `char*`.  `char*` - c ним путаница, т.к. отображение зависит от кодировки (из за того, что 256 символов не хватает для отображения текстов), для `wchar_t*` проблемы с кодировкой отпадают (ну если не используется китайский или емодзи или что-то из новой новой символики). А utf-8 для с++ - неизвесный "иностранный" язык. Ещё можно сконвертировать в char-1251, если среда настроена на 1251 то она правильно отобразит строку.

Comment: @nick_n_a А почему вы думаете, что `wchar` с китайским или эмоджами не справится? Там ведь честный UTF-16.

Comment: @zed потому что разработчики с++ могут вполне подключить "устаревший" шрифт, или неверно выбрать шрифт так, что такие символы там будут отсутствовать:) Емодзи - часть влезет, а такой U+1F3C0 (баскетбольный мяч) - нет. Китайские - это в качестве шутки. Китайский и правда в unicode хорошо реализован.

Comment: Прошлая версия вопроса была совершенно другой. Для записи utf-8 в `wstring` необходимо конвертация кодировки, так как `wstring` не может содержать текст в кодировке utf-8. А вот отобразить utf-8 в массиве char - можно

Comment: @VTT и все же я не понимаю как мне получить UTF-8 и где хранить его

Comment: Хранить в `vector<char>` или в `std::string`

Comment: @VTT std::string подходит для UTF-8? а в чем смысл std::wstring?

Comment: std::string подходит для хранения массива char с нулем на конце. а wstring подходит для хранения массива wchar с нулем на конце, т.е. UCS-16 / UTF-16 или UTF-32

Comment: А вам для винды подойдёт?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для windows. Так как часто приходилось сталкиваться с кодировками, предлагаю попробовать "решение в лоб", т.е. я вижу, что в формате юникод wchar_t хранятся данные в формате UTF-8. Можно преобразовать их в char и обратно в юникод.  Не самое лучшее решение (некоторые символы, т.е. всё что верх но не кирилица - будут потеряны).

```
if(curl) { /*...*/ }  // чисто показать после какого куска вписать код
int utf8_len = readBuffer.length();
char * tmp = (char*)malloc(utf8_len+1);// просим место    
utf8_len  = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0,readBuffer.c_str(), utf8_len , tmp , utf8_len , 0, 0);
tmp[utf8_len]=0;
wchar_t * wtmp = (wchar_t*)malloc(utf8_len*2+2);
wsprintfW(wtmp,L"%hs",tmp); // Всё, получили стандартный юникод
readBuffer.assign(wtmp); // присвоить результат
// ну и всё освободить
free((void*)tmp);
free((void*)wtmp);
```

Другие варианты решения:

- В ADO есть преобразователь
- Поискать инфу по преобразованию кодировок
- Можно просто преобразовать wchar в char циклом, и взять ф-цию MultiByteToWideChar вместо WideCharToMultiByte, но не пробовал...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763237.aspx
- возможно это [Нужен пример использования g_convert()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872427/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-g-convert?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Попробуйте такое решение

```
int utf8_len = readBuffer.length();
char * tmp = (char*)malloc(utf8_len+1);// просим место    
for (int i=0;i<utf8_len;i++) tmp[i]=(char)readBuffer[i];
wchar_t * wtmp = (wchar_t*)malloc(utf8_len*2+2);    
utf8_len  = MultiByteToWideChar (
   CP_UTF8, 0,tmp,utf8_len, wtmp , utf8_len );
wtmp[utf8_len]=0;
readBuffer.assign(wtmp); // присвоить результат    
free((void*)tmp);
free((void*)wtmp);
```