# Преобразование LPWSTR в string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Доброе утро! Пытаюсь извлечь имена пользователей из структуры LPUSER_INFO_3, они хранятся в wchar_t* (LPWSTR). Мне необходимо преобразовать их в string или String^, чтобы в дальнейшем выводить на форму в один из компонентов. Использовала:

```
 string stkj = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, (ui->usri3_name), -1,
                                    NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL)
```

Но ничего не получилось... Как это исправить? Прошу помощи...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WideCharToMultiByte конвертирует строку, но добавляет мусор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839080/widechartomultibyte-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80)

Comment: Переведите в `char*` потом воспользуйтесь конструктором `new string(char*)`

Comment: Ещё варианты http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339960/how-do-i-convert-wchar-t-to-stdstring

Answer (score 0):

[WideCharToMultiByte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) возвращает не строку, а число символов результирующей строки, включая завершающий ноль. В вашем конкретном варианте вызов этой функции означает "*взять завершенную нулем WCHAR строку `ui->usri3_name`, подсчитать ее длину, и вернуть минимальный размер буфера, в который поместится эта строка в UTF-8*".

Преобразовать можно, например, так:

```
int len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (ui->usri3_name), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
LPSTR s8 = (LPSTR)_alloca(len);
::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (ui->usri3_name), -1, s8, len,  NULL, NULL);
string stkj = s8;
```

Первый вызов `WideCharToMultiByte` определяет необходимый размер буфера для преобразованной строки, а второй и выполняет собственно преобразование.

Еще надо заметить, что `_alloca` нельзя использовать в частности в блоках `catch`. В этом случае его надо заменить его на

```
LPSTR s8 = new char [len];
. . .
delete [] s8;
```

или использовать какой-нибудь вариант умных указателей.